# pass variables as function param does not work - syntax issue?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a function which changes my `img` src and fades it in and out:

```
function changeImg(e, f) {
    $('#image').fadeOut(300, function(){
        $(this).attr('src', e+f.img).bind('onreadystatechange load', function(){
           if (this.complete) $(this).fadeIn(300);
        });
    });
}
```

as you can see I pass two parameters which is  `var imgArr` and `var curr` which is given in this `.click()` function:

```
var imgArr = [{ object1: '..', object2: '..', img: 'image1.png'}, and more array elements];
$divs.click(function() {
    var curr = $(this).index();

    // function where I pass imgArr (an array) and var curr
    changeImg(imgArr, curr);
});
```

the problem is `changeImg()` does not work. It simply does not know the array and curr. When I put the function inside the click handler everything works fine `imgArr` and `curr` is known. I assume it could be a syntax problem? Do I have to write `e+f` different? I tried `e+[f]` as well.

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:** to make it clearer I want to have inside the `changeImg` the following:

```
$(this).attr('src', imgArr[curr].img).bind(...);
```

Comment: @AmitJoki sorry but what is unclear? I try to edit then!

Comment: Why are you trying to do `+`?

Comment: @wander that was it, wanna make an answer?

Comment: just wondering, instead of passing both the array and the index, why don't you just pass the new src value? (eg `changeImg(imgArr[curr])`)

Comment: @BeNdErR well thats a good point actually! Don't know why I didn't thought about!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that e is an array of objects and f is the index of the wanted item you should use:

```
$(this).attr('src', e[f].img);
```

But I think this is just one step in the right direction then.